# NeoVim-LUA: can vim.b only hold read-only data?

Tags: neovim, lua

I'm writing a plugin for NeoVim in Lua and I'm trying to keep the state of my plugin in the `vim.b` table:

```
vim.b.myplugin = vim.b.myplugin or {
    "property" = "value",
    ...
}
```

But it turns out, that I can't change any properties later on. All values remain the same.

Here is a oneliner showing the problem:

```
:lua vim.b.myplugin = {p = "a"} ; print(vim.b.myplugin.p) ; vim.b.myplugin.p = "b" ; print(vim.b.myplugin.p)
```

prints

```
a
a
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I store my buffer-specific state in a lua plugin?

Comment: This is "a known issue". https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#caveats-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that neovim creates a new table each time a b type variable is accessed ;

```
:lua vim.b.myplugin = {p = "a"}; print(vim.b.myplugin); print(vim.b.myplugin);

table: 0x7f09e16bcb28                                                                                           
table: 0x7f09e15aca80
```

Any modifications to the table are not propagated back to the buffer variable; for instance this also does not work;

```
lua vim.b.myplugin = {p = "a"};
x = vim.b.myplugin; print(vim.inspect(x));
x.p = "b"; print(vim.inspect(vim.b.myplugin))
```

One workaround would be to replace the table wholly

```
val = vim.b.myplugin
val.p = "b"
vim.b.myplugin = val
```

Alternatively you can use a global variable indexed by buffer

```
bufg = {}
bufg[vim.fn.bufnr()] = {p = "a"}
```

But of course, this never makes it to a real buffer variable in `b:`.